# Escaping double quotes in php

Tags: php

I have the following variable being dynamically set by user generated content:

```
$variable = '<a href="http://www.mysite.com/article">This Article</a>';
```

When this variable is set, I then echo it as such

```
echo $variable;
```

I know that as is, this wouldn't be valid because I would need to escape the double quotes etc.

Is there a way to automate the process to make the variable printable as a clickable link, thus escaping the quotes in my variable automatically?

---

Edit:
Turns out this is indeed perfectly valid, but this being used on a joomla site, html tags are being stripped out, and I have to use [[a href]] instead of the regular <>.
Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: Exactly what do you think is invalid about echoing that string?

Comment: It only prints out the text This Article, isntead of presenting my link, so I assumed that the presence of double-quotes in my url is what breaks it?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with that statement

Comment: Can we see the HTML output from the echo?

Comment: Err, no. It only prints `This Article` because the anchor tag `<a ...> ... </a>` makes it a link. It has nothing to do with the quotes.

Comment: Warning: Unexpected character in input: ''' (ASCII=39) state=1 in urlhere  : eval()'d code on line 1  
Is what I get!

Comment: @skarama: You didn’t tell anything about `eval`.

Comment: It does present it but it does not allow me to click it, it writes it as text rather then a clickable link

Comment: #Gumbo ,sorry if I omitted important information, I have no idea what it even means, but I'll add it to my initial post.

Comment: @skarama: Just show us your whole code (the parts that matter) and tell us what you intend to do.

Comment: Here you go, hope it helps, and thanks!

Comment: @skarama: But where (any why) do you call `eval` where the error occurs?

Comment: I don't call it anywhere personnally, but I'm on a Joomla site which invokes tons of things I have no knowledge of. Do you think this is simply an interference with some other function some other place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to use your exact code in a php page I have and it acts as you need it to.  Seems to be working just fine for me.

Answer (score 7):

To display the string "as it is" in a browser, you must pass it through `htmlspecialchars()`.

```
echo htmlspecialchars($variable);
```

If you don't, the browser interprets the HTML and displays the link text, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a problem with your code as-is...  You're using single quotes to contain the entire string, so it should output as a clickable link when *viewed in a browser*

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine and should be functional.

Comment: If the string was started with single quotes, double quotes do not need escaping. And vice versa.

Comment: that doesn't escape the double quotes because it's no surrounded in double quotes

Comment: This will actually display the backslashes.  The only character you need to escape inside single quotes is a single quote.