# show double quote in my page

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Escaping double quotes in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869695/escaping-double-quotes-in-php)

In my database, the record is shoing like `this is php's code and "called" a special code`.
When I am trying to fetch this text from mysql database to my php page, it is showing up to `this is php's code and`
  My code is simple:

```
$all_gallery_ph_sql = mysql_query("SELECT `path`,`name`,`title`,`details` FROM `gallery` WHERE `status`='1' AND `type`='myreference' AND `enable_status`='1' LIMIT {$startpoint} ,{$limit}");                                       
echo $res['details'];
```

[image]
So how to resolve this issue. Please help me. 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the entire string is in the database in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

```
echo htmlentities( $gallerycontent['content'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: @phpdeveloper Are you sure the example you provided is complete?

Comment: From admin panel I am just adding this details by using mysql_real_escape_string function and after uploading in DB, I am fetching this in my front-end page. Moreover I can say that, in the table structure, the collation of the 'content' field is 'utf8_general_ci'.

Comment: @phpdeveloper Have you checked the contents of your database using, e.g., PHPMyAdmin? In other words: Is the string correctly added to the database?

Comment: Ya I have tested that. Its added successfully. Please see the attached image.

Comment: @phpdeveloper You select by a field `cms_id`, which I can't find in the screenshort. Are you sure it's the correct entry?

Comment: I am very sorry. The screenshot is correct but the query was not correct. Please see the updated question.

Comment: I am very sorry please unblock me.

Comment: @phpdeveloper "unblock"?

Comment: Actually I am not able to ask any new question.It is showing "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more."
So is there any chance to get back my account?

Comment: @phpdeveloper I have no clue about that one. Maybe you should ask on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) about this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22826/discussion-between-phpdeveloper-and-sirko)

Comment: @phpdeveloper: Did you visit the link given: http://goo.gl/C1Kwu?  Blocking is done automatically by the site, we users have no control over that.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat That means there is no way to continue with the new question?

Comment: @phpdeveloper: The link should explain that to you.